# Find the constant value of an exponent

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following general solution for an antiderivative: `x(t) = e^C*e^(at) - 1` and I now need to find the particular solution when x(0.01) and t = 0.

This equates to: `0.01 = e^C - 1` which is `1.01 = e^C`. How can I get the value of C?

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you heard of the natural logarithm?

Comment: You get $C$ by means of the logarithm, but you actually don't need to. Leave the solution as $x(t)=1.01e^{at}-1$, which is better than $x(t)=e^{0.009950330\cdots}e^{at}-1$.

Comment: @Hews Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Taking the natural $\log$ both sides, we have

$$1.01=e^C \iff \ln (1.01)=\ln (e^C) \iff C=\ln (1.01)$$

indeed recall that

$$\ln (e^C)=C\ln e= C \cdot 1 = C$$

Comment: Thanks! Why don't I take the "+1" from the RHS and add it to the LHS though?

Comment: @Hews Sorry, I don't understand your point. Could you please explain it better?

Comment: So I have 0.01 = e^C - 1 initially. Don't I need to change that to 1.01 = e^c?

Comment: @Hews Opssss yes sorry, my mistake I fix that typo!

Comment: Thank you! I'm also trying to find the particular solution for this: x(t) =(Ke^(bt))/(1+Ke^(bt)) and I have C = ln(0.01), is that correct?

Comment: @Hews We need to consider the genral solution $x(t)=x_h(t)+x_p(t)$ and then apply the initial condition $x(0)=x_0$ to find the value for the constant contained into the homogeneous part $x_h(t)$.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain that well enough. That's the general solution there, the original equation was dx/dt = bx(1-x).

Comment: @Hews We should have $x(t)=e^{bt}/(C+e^{bt})$ and $x(0)=1/(C+1)=0.01 \implies C=99$.

Comment: @Hews If you have new questions, you can formulate a new OP for that.